# Regex statement for [8 characters]-[4 characters]

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to create a Regex statement in JavaScript to search for a string that looks like this `d64rtad4-a232-9811-jc82-6h20be9u8w12` and find it's character position in a larger string (line of text).

The specific letters and numbers can be any lowercase letter or number but it is always: 
`[8 characters]-[4 characters]-[4 characters]-[4 characters]-[12 characters]`

Can someone get me started on how I would go about this? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by: `find it's character position in a larger string (line of text)`? What character are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is pretty straight-forward. The symbols you look for are described by `[a-z0-9]` character class, so just stick those together with proper quantifiers and surround with proper boundaries:

```
var patt = /\b[a-z0-9]{8}(?:-[a-z0-9]{4}){3}-[a-z0-9]{12}\b/;
```

The positioning part is only a bit trickier: [**RegExp.exec()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method returns `null`, if match is failed, or an object with `index` property, if match succeeds. And that's, obviously, exactly what you need. So the code looks like this:

```
var res = patt.exec(someLongString);
var pos = res && res.index;
```

As a result, you'll have either `null` in `pos` variable (meaning that no pattern has been matched), or the 0-based position of the matching substring.

Answer (score 1):

```
\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yX3pL1/1)

Or more specific:

```
[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}
```

[regex101 again](https://regex101.com/r/yX3pL1/3)